# Django error in creating model

Tags: python, django

I'm having an issue with creating a user profile with a foreign object.

I have a user and I want to attach an account type to that user.

**model.py**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, unique=True)

class Account(models.Model):
    reports = models.IntegerField(default=3)
    accounttype = models.CharField(default='Free', max_length=250)
    description = models.CharField(default='N/A', max_length=250)
    monthlycost = models.FloatField(default=0.0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username + " - " + self.accounttype
```

The issue is I'm getting the below error:

```
account = models.ForeignKey(Account, unique=True)
NameError: name 'Account' is not defined
```

How do I call the Account class for the foreign key?

Comment: Rearrange your file so `Account` is declared first.

Comment: put your Account class on top of UserProfile class

Comment: John Gordon moving account up worked

Answer (score 0):

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    account = models.ForeignKey("app_name.Account", unique=True)

class Account(models.Model):
    reports = models.IntegerField(default=3)
    accounttype = models.CharField(default='Free', max_length=250)
    description = models.CharField(default='N/A', max_length=250)
    monthlycost = models.FloatField(default=0.0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username + " - " + self.accounttype
```

You can use `"app_name.Account"`instead of `Account`. Replace `app_name` with the name of your app.

Comment: have you tried by executing this, does it really working

Answer (score 0):

As per  John Gordon comment, I moved Account above UserProfile and it worked

```
class Account(models.Model):
    reports = models.IntegerField(default=3)
    accounttype = models.CharField(default='Free', max_length=250)
    description = models.CharField(default='N/A', max_length=250)
    monthlycost = models.FloatField(default=0.0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username + " - " + self.accounttype


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, unique=True)
```

Thanks guys :)